The table is cutting of on the bottom
The table on the bottom is cutting of while searching on mobile phone (it works fine on desktop)
you can access the web at https://cirrostrats.onrender.com/ (search 4399) to get the table
Attaching the screenshot as well

I tried editing the css for mobile and desktop site but the table is still cutting off on he bottom part
the code snippet


.accordion-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease;
}

.accordion-content.active {
  max-height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
<div id="departure-container" class="table-container">
  <div class="accordion-button-container">
    <div class="accordion-content active" id="departure-content-{{ departure_ID }}">
      <table class="comparison-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <div class="header-button" onclick="toggleAccordion('departure-content-{{ departure_ID }}')">
                &#9660; Departure
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <td style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">
            <span style="float: left; width: 33%;">{{ scheduled_departure_time }}</span>
            <span style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: center;">{{ departure_ID }}</span>
            <span style="float: right; width: 33%; text-align: right;">{{ departure_gate }}</span>
          </td>


          <!-- Here got rid of for loops, makes it easier to work with design. -->
          <!-- TODO: Make it easier to replicate and reuse code without having to duplicate. extract this out to a new file for use one... -->
          <!-- Maybe seperate out html alltogether in a different html file using >>> include 'partial_template1.html'  -->

          <!-- This is the first section has the zulu time and type of weather -->
          <tr>
            <td>D-ATIS <span class="small-text"> {{ dep_datis_zt|safe }}</span> </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- This is the second section has the weather itself-->
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left; font-family: Menlo, monospace;">{{dep_datis |safe}}</td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
            <td>METAR <span class="small-text"> {{ dep_metar_zt |safe }}</span> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left; font-family: Menlo, monospace;">{{dep_metar |safe}}</td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
            <td>TAF <span class="small-text"> {{ dep_taf_zt |safe}}</span> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="dep_taf_cell" style="text-align: left; font-family: Menlo, monospace; white-space: wrap; overflow: scroll; text-overflow: ellipsis; max-height: none; height: auto;" title="{{dep_taf | safe}}">
              {{dep_taf | safe}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>



this is the part cutting of
<td id="dep_taf_cell" style="text-align: left; font-family: Menlo, monospace; white-space: wrap; overflow: scroll; text-overflow: ellipsis; max-height: none; height: auto;" title="{{dep_taf | safe}}">{{dep_taf | safe}}


Please [edit] and scroll to the snippet I made you and change it to RENDERED HTML and RELEVANT CSS. We want to see a [mcve]

Please also read: Can I link to my website

The problem is within the css of accordion-content. Just remove it from the div element.
You are setting the max-height attribute and therefore its height is limited.
FYI: The problem can also happen on standard web and is not restricted to mobile. It's triggered by the content of your table and if its height exceeds the max-height limit you set.

Where did you get the CSS from if not the question?

He provided a link to the website and i inspected it.

Why a max-height at all? Why not just not have it there?

Yes, you are absolutely right. Just seen that he sets the max-height to 1000px and in the next class he sets it to 0px

Answering questions that do not have the problem visible IN THE QUESTION is frowned upon here since they are USELESS to people coming later.

Makes sense, could have thought of that myself...
